# JPAException occur when trying to access to any page after Secure login

Tags: jpa, playframework

On my website using Play!, I have an Admin part. All Admin controllers have a `@With` and a `@Check` annotation.

When disconnected, everything goes fine.
When connected, each time I load a page (any page, admin or not), a `JPAException` is raised.

---

Here is the Admin checker :

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {

    static boolean authentify(String username, String password) {
        return User.connect(username, password) != null;
    }

    static boolean check(String profile) {
        User user = User.find("byLogin", connected()).<User>first(); /**line 12**/
        renderArgs.put("user", user.login);
        if ("admin".equals(profile)) {
            return user.role == Role.Admin;
        } else if ("manager".equals(profile)) {
            return user.role == Role.Manager || user.role == Role.Admin;
        } else if ("user".equals(profile)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the exception :

```
JPA error
A JPA error occurred (The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.): 

play.exceptions.JPAException: The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.
at play.db.jpa.JPA.get(JPA.java:22)
at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:51)
at play.db.jpa.JPQL.em(JPQL.java:16)
at play.db.jpa.JPQL.find(JPQL.java:44)
at models.User.find(User.java)
at controllers.Security.check(Security.java:12)
at play.utils.Java.invokeStaticOrParent(Java.java:159)
at controllers.Secure$Security.invoke(Secure.java:193)
at {play}/framework/templates/tags/404.html.(line:1)
at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:213)
at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:347)
at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:213)
at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:247)
at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
at play.server.PlayHandler.serve404(PlayHandler.java:634)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

---

This actually doesn't bother the application (it works fine), but I really don't know why this occurs...

Thanks in advance !

---

EDIT :

The User class code :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Email
    public String email;

    @Required @Password
    public String password;

    public String fullname;

    @Required @Column(unique=true)
    public String login;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Role role=Role.User;

    public static User connect(String login, String password) {
        return find("byLoginAndPassword", login, password).first();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return login;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your model class have @Entity anotation?

Comment: I'm skeptical that your application is working fine, but let's see the code for your User class

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncommented the following code in your **application.conf** ?

```
db=mem
```

Play starts the JPA context only if database is activated in application.conf.

Comment: Ok, so it's seems the JPA context is not yet bound when you are in the check. But it will when you will be inside the controller...

Comment: Are you sure that User class is annotated with JPA's entity, not Hibernate's one ? Play is loading the JPA context only when @Entity JPA's annotation is found, not with Hibernate's one.

Comment: Maybe you faced this problem : http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/755-wrong-plugin-execution-order-in-dev-mode . Try to use the latest version of Play (use the master's one, download it from Github). The bug seems to be corrected in the master branch.